# How to collapse TextArea text to be inside the TextArea width in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, textarea

I am using TextArea to display some text in GWT and I want to support collapsing the text. Please see below example:
The text before collapse should be look like:

```
'name': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

The text after collapsing should be look like:

```
 'name': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(...)'
```

In order to do that, I need to know the width of the TextArea and comparing it to the length of the string. There are two methods in TextArea related to width: `getOffsetWidth` and `getCharacterWidth`. I tested but none of them work. How can I get the width of the TextArea based in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that they dont work? What result are you getting?

If you are not getting any width you might be calling the methods before the widget has been added to the DOM. Then it will not have any width or height yet.

Are you sure you are calling the methods after the widget has been properly added to the DOM?

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.getOffsetWidth(); // no width
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(textArea);
textArea.getOffsetWidth(); // Here we have a width
```